# I like the way you’re walking in the hall. V.s. I like the way how you walk in the hall

Tags: grammar

When I dropped off my kid at school. I heard the teacher said “I like the way **you’re walking** in the hall.” or “I like **how you walk** in the hall.”
I would say, "I like **the way how you walk** in the hall."
Which one is correct? And why?

Comment: No, you can't say *"the way how". Your first example is correct: "I like the way (that) you’re walking in the hall". Your second example "I like how you walk in the hall" is marginal, and best avoided

Comment: I heard the teacher also said " I like how you walk in the hall."

Comment: As I said, it is only marginally acceptable, and best avoided. Your teacher should not use it.

Answer (score 1):

"*... the way you walk...*" and "*... how you walk...*" are correct and natural.

"*... the way how you walk...*" is ungrammatical.

"The way" describes *how* you walk, so "the way how" is redundant. It means, "... the way the way you walk".

You might be conflating the use of "that" with "how" because "*I like the way **that** you walk*" is correct and natural.

Answer (score 0):

> [1] *I like the way you walk in the hall*.
>
> [2] *%I like how you walk in the hall.*
>
> [3] * *I like the way how you walk in the hall.*

In simple terms:

[1] is fine and the usual way of conveying this particular meaning.

[2] is only marginally acceptable (some dialects).

[3] is flat ungrammatical.